# SharePoint workflow to send e-mail notification

Tags: workflow

SharePoint workflow to send e-mail notification...The notification mail should contains which column data is changed or updated in the form ..
Get me the solution

Comment: Hio and welcome to SP.SE Arul. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? 2010, 2013?

Comment: SP 2010...i tried using workflow...to send email notification...i got the updated data..but i cant get previous data which is modified now..what come i do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know of doing this is creating a custom workflow action that reads the version history of the list item. They have one already that is free or if you don't trust the code that would be your route. Since there is no way to read version history with an OOTB workflow I don't see how you can get the original data. Another method would be to create an onchange workflow that writes to another list that references the original item and writes out the data with a timestamp and then does a verification against that list to see what fields changed since the last change. I think the later solution would be more efficient... but if you need to do it ootb I would take the last solution. below is a link to the custom action you need.

http://verhistoryactivity.codeplex.com/